# How to replace values in a column in a table by condition in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have a table named "building" in PostgreSQL. It has several columns and millions of rows. Each row has a unique id. It looks like

```
id        tags    height     building:levels    area
 1   apartment     58 m                  17      109
 2   apartment     null                null      111
 3        shed        7                   2    75sqm
 4  greenhouse       6m                   3      159
 5  industrial       16                 2;4      105
 6  commercial       27                   8      474
```

And I have another csv file with cleaned data for column `height` and `building:levels`. The csv looks like:

```
id    height     building:levels  
 1       58                  17   
 3        7                   2  
 4        6                   3  
 5       16                   4 
 6       27                   8
```

I want to join the csv file back to the table on the server, and the final outcome might look like this:

```
id        tags    height     building:levels    area
 1   apartment       58                  17      109
 2   apartment     null                null      111
 3        shed        7                   2    75sqm
 4  greenhouse        6                   3      159
 5  industrial       16                   4      105
 6  commercial       27                   8      474
```

I want to replace the values in `height` and `building:levels` where the `id` are the same in the table and the csv file. I've tried to import data from csv but it didn't replace the values, only adding new rows. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is a horrible data model. Do you have any chance of fixing that before you continue? Btw: your SQL client (DBeaver) is irrelevant for this question.

Comment: You can import the csv file data in a temporary table first, and then update the building table from that temporary table. @a_horse_with_no_name : I don't see here something horrible ... can you enlighten me ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the suggestions! Could you elaborate more on why the data model is horrible and how can I fix it? I'm getting a bit lost on this

Comment: @Edouard Thanks for the suggestion! But I'm quite new to this area, how can I update the building table from the temporary table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the csv file data in a temporary table first :

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS building_temp LIKE building ;
COPY building_temp (id, height, "building:levels") FROM your_csv_file.csv WITH options_list ;
```

See the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-copy.html) for building the options_list.

and then update the building table from that temporary table

```
UPDATE building AS b
   SET height = bt.height
     , "building:levels" = bt."building:levels"
  FROM building_temp AS bt
 WHERE b.id = bt.id
```